# How to change MongoDB v3.4 maxWriteBatchSize limit

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am currently using a MongoDB V3.4 in production environment and have to insert data in bulk from another MongoDB same version. I am currently achieving this by using a tool which tails the oplogs of the primary DB and replicates those ops in my destination DB. However, sometimes is get an error like "Write batch sizes must be between 1 and 1000. Got 2000" and process stops. I did some digging and found the maxWriteBatchSize limit is 1000 in MongoDB v<3.5. Can I bypass or change this limit?

Answer (score 0):

That limit is hardcoded at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.4.24/src/mongo/s/write_ops/batched_command_request.cpp#L43

```
const size_t BatchedCommandRequest::kMaxWriteBatchSize = 1000;
```

In order to change it, you would have to recompile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply....Can you please suggest a way to do this as i have already MongoDb installed on the machine.

Comment: Then the change would have to be in the tool that does the inserting.

Comment: I tried that but the error still comes....can i change it somewhere in MongoDB files

Comment: The 1000-document batch limit is compiled in, and there is no configuration option for it.  You will need to either restructure the inserting app to use batches smaller than 1000, or recompile the mongod binary from source to permit larger batches.